# Python Boolean and Logical Operators

Tags: python, boolean, operator-keyword, logical-operators

Given two input boolean values I want to print out the following results:

> True True ->  False
>   True False -> False
>   False True -> False
>   False False ->  True

I tried doing this:

```
if boolInput1 and boolInput2 == True:
    print(False)
elif boolInput1 == True and boolInput2 == False:
    print(False)
elif boolInput1 == False and boolInput2 == True:
    print(False)
elif boolInput1 and boolInput2 == False:
    print(True)
```

but it doesn't work as this is the output:

```
Test  Input    Expected Actual 
1   True True   False   False
2   True False  False   False
3   False True  False   False
4   False False True    False
```

I've tried searching for an answer online but can't find anything.

Comment: `print(not boolInput1 and not boolInput2)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That would return `True` for the first case and `False` for all the others.

Comment: @smarx Sorry, I misread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boolInput1 and boolInput2 == False` doesn't do what you think. The `==` binds more tightly than the `and`, so you're testing "is boolInput1 (truthy), and is boolInput2 equal to False", when you want "is boolInput1 False and boolInput2 False too?", which would be expressed `boolInput1 == False and boolInput2 == False` or more Pythonically, `not boolInput1 and not boolInput2`.

Really, you're making this harder than it needs to be. All of your code could simplify to just:

```
print(not boolInput1 and not boolInput2)
```

or extracting the `not` if you prefer it:

```
print(not (boolInput1 or boolInput2))
```

No `if`, `elif`, `else` or any other blocks required.

Generally speaking, explicitly comparing to `True` or `False` is not Pythonic; just use implicit "truthiness" testing to work with any types. Since you need `not` here anyway, the end result will always be `True` or `False`, even if the inputs aren't booleans at all, where directly comparing to `True` or `False` will make inputs like `2`, `None`, or `[]` behave differently from the way they traditionally behave in "truthiness testing" (they'd be truthy, falsy and falsy respectively).

Answer (score 2):

This could be much simpler.

```
if bool1 or bool2:
    print(False)
else:
    print(True)
```

You can also, I believe, do

```
print(not(bool1 or bool2))
```

which is simpler still.

Comment: I think you have that backwards.

Comment: I'm not sure if the edit has been made yet, but this is still wrong. I believe all the other answers have it right. :-)

Comment: As a test case, what if `bool1` is `True` and `bool2` is `False`? The correct answer is `False`, but your code would print `True`.

Comment: @smarx, geesh, I'm just failing here, aren't I? Let me fix this.

Comment: No need to fix... there are already several correct answers. But if you want to be different, go for `if bool1 or bool2: print(False)` and `print(not(bool1 or bool2))`.

Comment: (Oops, one of the answers alraedy has the latter.)

Comment: @smarx right, thank you. I apologize for the mess here =)

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
print(not boolInput1 and not boolInput2)
```

The issue with your code is here:

```
elif boolInput1 and boolInput2 == False:
    print(True)
```

That would work if it read:

```
elif boolInput1 == False and boolInput2 == False:
    print(True)
```

This line works fine despite having the same kind of issue, because the `if boolInput1` does roughly what you want (checks for a truthy value).

```
if boolInput1 and boolInput2 == True:
```

It might be better to write it this way to be more consistent with your other checks:

```
if boolInput1 == True and boolInput2 == True:
```

Answer (score 0):

`elif boolInput1 and boolInput2 == False:` isn't doing what you think it's doing.

Each side of the and are evaluated as separate booleans.

To condense what the computer is doing on that statement:

```
boolInput1 and boolInput2 == False
False and False == False
False and True
False #Does not enter if Statement
```

This should show you that your logic on all 4 is actually wrong and there are ways to mess it up. Try to avoid `boolean == true` kind of statements wherever possible, and just say `if boolean`

Working version:

```
if boolInput1 and boolInput2:
    print(False)
elif boolInput1 and not boolInput2:
    print(False)
elif not boolInput1 and boolInput2:
    print(False)
elif not boolInput1 and not boolInput2:
    print(True)
```

Though depending on your reason for this code, there are even more simple ways to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Your truth table is just exclusive-or.

bool1 ^ bool2

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
bools = [True, False]
for bool1 in bools:
    for bool2 in bools:
        print(bool1, bool2, bool1 ^ bool2)

True True False
True False True
False True True
False False False
```

Comment: This is clearly wrong.